# Share CSS between different Ionic Apps

Tags: css, angular, sass, ionic2

I have a some css files of my style guide and I want share this files between the different apps. What is the best practice to do this?

Answer (score 2):

I could recommend creating a new repo with all your generic styles and then integrate it as a submodule of each of your apps. More info:

https://github.com/blog/2104-working-with-submodules

Hope it helps.

Comment: For now, I create a npm package containing my theme files, intall in my apps and import my theme on variables.scss file.